# Is this true about groups

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ and $H$ are two non-abelian group. Let [G,G] be the commutator subgroup of $G$ then $G/[G, G]$ will be abelian.

**Question :** Is it true that $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic iff $G/[G,G]$ and $H/[H, H]$ are isomorphic.

Comment: "Yes" would make the classification of finite simple groups a lot easier!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown You may as well drop the "finite".

Comment: Try with the first two or three non-abelian groups you can find! There is one of order 6 and two of order 8 that you should try. Once you've done that, come back to us if you're still uncertain. (Please do; I'm actually slightly  curious as to what the result is.)

Answer (score 3):

For a perfect group $G$ you have that $G/[G,G]$ is the trivial group. Thus, the statement is false (take for example the alternating groups $A_5$ and $A_6$).

Answer (score 1):

A consequence of that would be that any two groups $G$ such that $G=[G,G]$ are isomorphic. Since that's clearly not the case…